# How to add generated sources for scala protobuf plugin using gradle?

Tags: scala, gradle, intellij-idea, protocol-buffers

I use gradle for building and want to generate some scala code for protobuf using this plugin: https://github.com/CharlesAHunt/scalapb-gradle-plugin

My gradle.build:

```
group 'xxxx'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "gradle.plugin.com.charlesahunt:scalapb-plugin:1.2.4"
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

apply plugin: 'com.charlesahunt.scalapb'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'scala'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8


dependencies {
    implementation 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.12.8'

    compile group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-classic', version: '1.2.3'
    compile group: 'com.typesafe', name: 'config', version: '1.3.4'

    testCompile group: 'org.scalatest', name: 'scalatest_2.12', version: '3.0.8'

}

scalapbConfig {
    protocVersion = "-v360"
    grpc = false
    targetDir = "build/generated/scala"
    projectProtoSourceDir = "src/main/protobuf"
    extractedIncludeDir = "build/external_protos"
}

sourceSets {
    generated {
        scala.srcDirs += "build/generated/"
    }
}

compileScala {
    dependsOn scalapb
}
```

The problem is that generated code isn't visible for my code and i can't use it. I tried to change `targetDir` and `scala.srcDirs` but it didn't help.

How can i solve this problem?

p.s. i use IntelliJ

Comment: Are you sure the generated code its not accesible? I mean, have you made a simple test and compile the project using **gradle** _(instead of **IntelliJ**)_ to see if it produces an error? - Because, it may be just an **IntellIJ** problem.

Comment: Probably, you're right that this may be an IntelliJ problem because i tried to compile my code using only IntelliJ. Initial googling showed me that i need to use IntelliJ plugin to solve it, but is this the only option?

Comment: no idea, I do not use **IntelliJ**, but I have see a couple of questions about code that doesn't work, that when you copy and pasted in on the **repl** worked without problems. Thus, I try to always suggest to check using a real compiler, so they can be sure where and what exactly is the problem. If you manage to confirm that this is an **IntellIJ** problem and not a **gradle**, or **scalapb** one, please reformulate the question so you can get attention for people that may know what is really happen ;)